# RecyclerView setOverScrollMode doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` seems to be ignoring `setOverScrollMode`. The value is set to `View.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS` and I see the overscroll glow in 5.1.1, but the content can't scroll.

Any ideas, what I can check?